# Display non UI thread forms on top of main form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

We have a form based application. It has two modal dialog running on non UI threads. Now the application has 3 forms. One main form and two forms running on non UI threads.

We need to display the non UI thread forms on the top of main form, if the user selected the application.

What should I do to do this?

Comment: "running on non UI threads" - seems unlikely.  Maybe not on the main UI thread, but unless there is a message pump handling windows messages, those forms will be unresponsive rectangles.

Comment: The two popups are displayed by calling Form.ShowDialog from the threads

Comment: That causes message pumps to be created for those threads, making them "UI" threads.

Comment: You should create your forms on the UI thread!

Answer (score 0):

Form has a [TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx) property that may do what you want.  Because of the poor threading, you may have mixed results.

```
myDialogForm.TopMost = true;

// Then either
myDialogForm.Show();
// or
myDialogForm.ShowDialog(parentForm);
```

Comment: The dialog you created is a modalless dialog. I tried with the TopMost property. When I set TopMost property, the dialogs are visible even though the main form is hidden behind some other application